# Pine script find the lowest low in a pivot

Tags: pivot, pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to find the lowest low price within a pivot.
I am using the ta.pivothigh() to get the pivot and then try to apply the ta.lowest() on that pivot to find its lowest price. But it doesn't work.

Here's my code

```
leftBars = input(4)
rightBars=input(4)


ph = ta.pivothigh(leftBars, rightBars)
lowestLow = ta.lowest(ph,rightBars+leftBars)

// Plot the pivot high  
plot(ph, style=plot.style_cross)
// Plot the pivot Low within rightBars
plot(lowestLow, style=plot.style_cross)
```

It successfully finds the pivots and plots a cross above the pivot high bar but it doesn't correctly find the lowest low. Instead, the lowestLow always coincides with the pivot high.
(The second plot() function, plots a cross at the same bar with the first plot()).

I guess the problem is at the `lowestLow = ta.lowest(ph,rightBars+leftBars)` line.